# NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter returns null

Tags: java, android, nfc

I have 3 different `devices` with `NFC`. On 2 of them `NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)` return what it should, but on third device returns`null`. There is app installed (not mine) on third device which works fine with `NFC cards`. The third device is `SUNMI P1N-G`. Any ideas?

Main Activity:

```
package com.test.nfctest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    TextView text1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter==null) {
            text1.setText("no nfc");
        } else {
            text1.setText("NFC");
        }

    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.nfctest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for getting null adapter.
http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.java#494

As per comments in NfcManager, there are two ways get the NFC Adapter:

1. Use {@link android.content.Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String)} with {@link Context#NFC_SERVICE} to create an {@link NfcManager}, then call {@link #getDefaultAdapter} to obtain the {@link NfcAdapter}.
   `NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
   NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();`
2. You can just call the static helper {@link NfcAdapter#getDefaultAdapter(android.content.Context)}.

You can try the alternative method #1 described above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering to old post.

On the Sunmi devices, at least on most of them, you need to use Sunmi Pay SDK to work with NFC and other cards.